# Nuxeo Source code installation Eroor

Tags: nuxeo

Hi i have tried installing nuxeo source code locally. but while installing it is giving the following error.

Please see the below screenshot to find the details about error.

https://prnt.sc/ih6k3z

https://prnt.sc/ih6jy6

Please Help me to solve the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in master branch of Nuxeo. Could you provide the Java version and the commit hash used for this installation?

Comment: my java version is 1.8 which is compatible with nuxeo

Answer (score 1):

I rarely have problem with the master branch and cannot reproduce your problem. However, there could be occasional failures depending on commits. I suggest you to retry again on today's master:

```
./clone.py master
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pdistrib
```

A more stable way to build Nuxeo source code is to use a tag (for release or fast-track), e.g. `release-9.10`, instead of using master:

```
./clone.py release-9.10
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pdistrib
```

If you're not familiar with the script `clone.py`, you can show the help message. It keeps a consistent clone for Nuxeo, its add-ons, and packages:

> ```
> $ ./clone.py --help
> Usage: clone.py [options] [version|branch|tag]
>
> Synopsis: ./clone.py master -a -m ""
>           Clone or update the Nuxeo Platform source code to the master branch, including all addons and Nuxeo Packages
>
> Clone or update Nuxeo Platform source code.
>
> Options:
>   -h, --help            show this help message and exit
>   -r REMOTE_ALIAS       the Git alias of remote URL (default: origin)
>   -a, --all             include 'optional' addons (default: False)
>   -f FALLBACK_BRANCH, --fallback=FALLBACK_BRANCH
>                         a branch to fallback on when the wanted branch doesn't exist locally neither remotely (default: none)
>   -n, --nodrivemapping  deactivate current directory mapping to a virtual drive on Windows
>   -m MARKETPLACE_CONF, --marketplace-conf=MARKETPLACE_CONF
>                         the Marketplace configuration URL (default: None)
>                         If set to '' (empty string), it defaults to 'https://raw.github.com/nuxeo/integration-scripts/master/marketplace.ini'
>   --mp-only             clone only package repositories (default: False)
> ```

Comment: Replace `git checkout <REF>` commands with `./clone.py <REF>` for a consistent clone.